# Getting JSON data from text area

Tags: javascript, json, textarea

In the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/660m7g7k/

```
<textarea id="input">
[
{
  name: "Tyorry",
  age: 22
}, {
  name: "greg",
 age: 44
}, {
  name: "aff",
  age: 99
}, {
  name: "ben",
  age: 20
}
]
```

```
var x=document.getElementById("input").value;
alert(x[0]);
```

There is JSON data, array of objects basically. I have 2 questions.

1) Is this JSON data in JSON.stringify format or JSON.parse format? since JSON.parse is erroring out and JSON.stringify is working properly.

2) Am getting the JSON data from textarea. but x[0] or x[3] is returning blank. basically i want to loop through the array item(which are objects) and get the values, name and age.

Answer (score 3):

The value in a text area is always a `string`. So if you want it as an object you'll want to use `JSON.parse()` to get it. If `JSON.Parse()` is failing then your JSON is in an invalid format.

To check if your JSON is valid, try using something like http://jsonlint.com/. The JSON provived in the fiddle is invalid.

Comment: Yes, [it does work](http://jsfiddle.net/660m7g7k/5/) with valid JSON, the property names need to be enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

In Plain JS use this

```
var x=document.getElementById("input").value;
var y = eval(x);
alert('hi '+y[0].name+ ' are you '+ y[0].age+' years old');
```

[Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/747zr8zm/)

Comment: The key is to convert String to a Javascript object. Eval is one way to do this however there are libraries that may help you. The best way to go is figure out what JS framework you will use - it is likely that you will find something it that toolbox. e.g. AngularJS, jQuery